# Google Analytics jquery event tracking not working

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking

I set up some Event Tracking code on a website with JQuery, by using the example provide on [this website](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/04/how-to-track-downloads-in-google-analytics/).

here is the core part of the jquery code I am using :

```
var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
var filePath = href;
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'Click-' + extension, filePath]);
if (jQuery(this).attr('target') != undefined && 
jQuery(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
                        setTimeout(function() { location.href = baseHref + href; }, 200);
                        return false;
                    }
```

But what I don't want is to have "Click-"... displayed in Google Analytics. 
But after removing this, and the code becoming :

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', extension, filePath]);
```

no more events are being tracked in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on this problem, I figured out that the **extension** variable :

```
 var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
```

isn't a string *(thanks to console.log(extension); in firebug)*. This can explain that Google Anyltics isn't showing any Events.

So the solution I came up with was to change my code to the following :

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', '' + extension, filePath]);
```

After this the tracking is working properly.